# How to display current URL into textbox on a tabbed browser?

Tags: vb.net, browser, textbox

I have already tried

```
TextBox1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
```

But I get back:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've done some debugging, and i can write the url to the debug terminal, but it seems i can't make anything equal CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString

EDIT:
I have solved this issue

Put This Into Your Form Load:

```
AddHandler wb.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1
```

Then Put This Into Your Code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    TextBox1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add web browser to tabcontrol1

```
  Dim ja As New WebBrowser
        Dim uri As New Uri("www.google.com")
        ja.Url = uri
        Dim i As New TabPage
        i.Controls.Add(ja)
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(i)
```

check url into the tabchanged

```
  Dim j As WebBrowser
        j = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser)
        j.Update()
        MessageBox.Show(j.Url.ToString)
```

Comment: Your code snippet did not work, I got the same error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
It was caused by:
TextBox1.Text = j.Url.ToString()

Comment: in all tab you have place web browser

Comment: So i have to place a webbrowser into my tabcontrol in design?

Comment: It doesn't let me do that i get the error:
"Cannot Add 'Web Browser' to TabControl. Only TabPages can be directly added to TabControls."

Comment: How do i do that? I'm not following you quite well.

Comment: Ah, Sorry about that. I tried your answer, and it gave me,
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(j.Url.ToString)

Comment: Dim j As WebBrowser
        j = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser)
        j.Update()
        MessageBox.Show(j.Url.ToString)